# JQuery - Exibir atributo Alt abaixo de cada imagem do slide

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

Então, preciso de ajuda com um código que estou tentando desenvolver. O site é todo em Wordpress, e possui um plugin chamado Master Slider. Preciso desenvolver um script que pegue o atributo Alt das imagens e exiba abaixo de cada imagem, e que esse atributo mude conforme a foto, obviamente.

**CÓDIGO JQUERY QUE POSSUO:**

```
    $( ".master-slider" ).append( "<p class='textoProduto'></p>" );
    $('.master-slider').each(function(){
    $(this).find('.textoProduto').html($(this).find('img').attr('alt')); 
    });
```

**HTML DO PLUGIN:**

```
    <!-- MasterSlider -->
    <div id="P_MS5a69ac9d1f2cf" class="master-slider-parent msl ms-parent-id-1" style="max-width:800px;"  >
        <!-- MasterSlider Main -->
        <div id="MS5a69ac9d1f2cf" class="master-slider ms-skin-default" >                    
        <div  class="ms-slide" data-delay="3" data-fill-mode="fill"  >
           <img src="http://www.sulpeneiras.com.br/wp-content/plugins/master-slider/public/assets/css/blank.gif" alt="contour-screen" title="" data-src="http://www.sulpeneiras.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/contour-screen-2-800x480.jpg" />
           <img class="ms-thumb" src="http://www.sulpeneiras.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/contour-screen-2-140x80.jpg" alt="contour-screen" />
<div class="ms-thumb" ><div class="ms-tab-context"><div class=&quot;ms-tab-context&quot;></div></div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div  class="ms-slide" data-delay="3" data-fill-mode="fill"  >
            <img src="http://www.sulpeneiras.com.br/wp-content/plugins/master-slider/public/assets/css/blank.gif" alt="PENEIRA-FABRICADO-EM-POLIETILENO" title="" data-src="http://www.sulpeneiras.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/PENEIRA-FABRICADO-EM-POLIETILENO-1-800x480.jpg" />
        <img class="ms-thumb" src="http://www.sulpeneiras.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/PENEIRA-FABRICADO-EM-POLIETILENO-1-140x80.jpg" alt="PENEIRA-FABRICADO-EM-POLIETILENO" />
        <div class="ms-thumb" ><div class="ms-tab-context"><div class=&quot;ms-tab-context&quot;></div></div>
       </div>               
    </div>
 </div>
<!-- END MasterSlider Main -->   
</div>
<!-- END MasterSlider -->
```

**O QUE EU QUERO QUE APAREÇA EM TODAS AS IMAGENS**
[image: O que quero que aconteça]

Mas o problema é que até agora só consegui mostrar o alt da primeira imagem do slide, e ele fica fixo para todos, e o que quero é, quando trocar o slide, trocar o texto do alt